# Error installing BizTalk Server 2013 R2 with the CAB file (Error verifying signature)

Tags: biztalk

I'm installing a development environment with BizTalk 2013 R2, but in the step of install the redistributable package (the CAB file) it always reports me "Error verifying signature of the redistributable component CAB file".

Any workaround?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually install the redistributable prerequisites.
look at this thread :

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17629.biztalk-server-redistributable-cab-files.aspx

Comment: I dos, but the installation process os cancelled always and It didn't recognize that the components are installed

Comment: It seems, Microsoft has killed all the links in that article

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Following link](https://blog.sandro-pereira.com/2021/08/20/biztalk-server-2016-error-the-redistributable-cab-file-does-not-have-a-valid-signature/)

Once you manually install each component from the CAB file, BizTalk installer will no longer asks for the redistribute CAB.